# Find form id by input values

Tags: jquery, html

How can I find a form ID with only the input values in jquery?

Example:
I want to get the form ID where `base=123` and `lot=2`

```html
    <form id="jobForm_0" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="base" value="123">
        <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="1">
    </form>
    <form id="jobForm_1" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="base" value="123">
        <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="2">
    </form>
    <form id="jobForm_2" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="base" value="456">
        <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="1">
    </form>
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried to create this yourself?

Comment: I've tried almost every find, closest, ect function, but my knowledge isn't that big enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var found = $('form[id]').filter(function() {
  return $("input[name=base][value=123]", this).length > 0 && $("input[name=lot][value=2]", this).length > 0
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var found = $('form[id]').filter(function() {
  return $("input[name=base][value=123]", this).length > 0 && $("input[name=lot][value=2]", this).length > 0
});

console.log($(found).attr("id"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="jobForm_0" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="base" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="1">
</form>
<form id="jobForm_1" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="base" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="2">
</form>
<form id="jobForm_2" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="base" value="456">
  <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: I'd go with `'form[id]'` just to be extra safe

Comment: I'd also be worried if OP was using non-hidden inputs where the value can be changed from the initial attribute. Still, nice answer

Comment: Where would you add this, don't follow 100% @Phil

Comment: The `form[id]` thing? In your initial selector. it just makes sure you're only looking at forms with `id` attributes

Answer (score 1):

you can give id to each an every element and then Use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1). It searches up the ancestors* of an element to find the first (closest) match.

```
$('#elementId').closest("form").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```js
var user_id = $('[name="base"][value="123"] + [name="lot"][value="2"]').closest("form").attr('id');
alert(user_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="jobForm_0" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="base" value="123">
        <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="1">
    </form>
    <form id="jobForm_1" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="base" value="123">
        <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="2">
    </form>
    <form id="jobForm_2" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="base" value="456">
        <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="1">
    </form>
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the OP's problem based on this statement `I want to get the form ID where base=123 and lot=2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").find('form').each(function(){ // loop to get all forms

    var base = $(this).find("input[name= 'base']").val();

    var lot = $(this).find("input[name= 'lot']").val();

    if(base == 123 && lot == 2){ // compare values by 123 & 2 , you can change as per your case
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var id= $('[name="base"][value="123"] + [name="lot"][value="2"]').parent().attr('id')
alert(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="jobForm_0" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="base" value="123">
        <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="1">
    </form>
    <form id="jobForm_1" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="base" value="123">
        <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="2">
    </form>
    <form id="jobForm_2" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="base" value="456">
        <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="1">
    </form>
```